# Перемещения поле или картинки в самом сайте PYTHON + React

Tags: python, django

Какую библиотеку нужно использовать, чтобы перемещать за ранее добавленные поля для ввода текста  как на сайтах без кода где берешь объект и перемещаешь. И как потом это все сохранить, чтобы после сохранение двигать объект будет нельзя?
например есть сайт canva.com/design/DAEqkinHy0w/FZFHoUrn7G6zyFQowYLTjA/edit там можно взять объект передвинуть и потом это все сохранить
PYTHON + React
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что и где вы хотите перемещать? Объекты в хранилище, элементы интерфейса в браузере? Лично мне не очень понятно.

Comment: может Вы имели в виду reaCt а не reaSt?

Comment: элементы интерфейса в браузере

Comment: Лично я не видел готовых решений для подобных операций. У Вас фронт отдельно работает, бекенд отдельно. Если Вы хотите что-то кастомное рисовать, и сохранять эти настройки для каждого пользователя, то вам все это ручками нужно делать. Сохранять настройки в хранилище и потом уже в соответствии с ними строить интерфейс.

Comment: например есть сайт https://www.canva.com/design/DAEqkinHy0w/FZFHoUrn7G6zyFQowYLTjA/edit там можно взять объект передвинуть и потом это все сохранить

Comment: Я не сомневаюсь, что они это сделали (по ссылке без инвайта никто никого не пускает) И я возвращаюсь к своему прошлому сообщению. Потому что принцип там абсолютно тот же самый. Когда вы работаете с элементами вы должны где то сохранять их свойства и настройки интерфейса, а потом уже строить интерфейс в соответствии с данными настройками